# I filtered an NSMutableArray of Dictionaries and then I want to filter for a Key again

Tags: swift, dictionary, filter, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
var dataArray : NSMutableArray = []
var sum = 0.00

func addNewIncomeRecord(_ id: String, date: String, description: String, amount: Double, currency: String, category: String, notes: String) {
    let dict = ["id" : id, "date" : date, "description" : description, "amount" : amount, "currency" : currency, "category" : category, "notes" : notes] as [AnyHashable : Any]

    dataArray.add(dict)
}

addNewIncomeRecord("1", date: "11-25", description: "Money", amount: 20.00, currency: "EUR", category: "Home", notes: "More Money")
addNewIncomeRecord("2", date: "11-25", description: "Rent", amount: 50.00, currency: "EUR", category: "Home", notes: "Rent Money")
addNewIncomeRecord("3", date: "11-25", description: "Hair", amount: 10.00, currency: "EUR", category: "Medical"  ,notes: "HairCut")

let homeValue = NSPredicate(format: "category == %@", "Home")
let filteredArray = (dataArray as NSMutableArray).filtered(using: homeValue)
print(filteredArray)
```

I filtered all Arrays of the "Home" category. But now I want filter the filteredArray again for the amounts. So that only the amounts of the two (Home Arrays) be in an extra Array.

Comment: This is Swift. Use `Array` instead of `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Use a Swift array and its `filtered` method instead of using `NSArray` and `NSPredicate`.

Comment: Yeah I know but this IS NOT IOS!! IT IS MACOS DEVELOPMENT! And in my App I have a NSTableView with rows! So that is the point why I use NSMutableArray!

Comment: Those suggestion apply to any Swift, regardless of OS.

Comment: I know but for my App, it is important to use an NSMutableArray, because I have an NSTableView with rows and columns of keys! And I also save the NSMutableArray  to a file!

Comment: You can use native Swift arrays with your `NSTableView` and there are ways to write a Swift array to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` in Swift. Use Swift native arrays (and dictionaries).
2. Once you do that, there is no need for `NSPredicate`. Use the `filter` method.
3. Don't use a dictionary to hold your data. Create a `struct` with the needed fields.

First, without creating a `struct`, here's a simply solution using native arrays:

```
var dataArray = [[String:Any]]()
var sum = 0.00

func addNewIncomeRecord(_ id: String, date: String, description: String, amount: Double, currency: String, category: String, notes: String) {
    let dict: [String:Any] = ["id" : id, "date" : date, "description" : description, "amount" : amount, "currency" : currency, "category" : category, "notes" : notes]

    dataArray.append(dict)
}

addNewIncomeRecord("1", date: "11-25", description: "Money", amount: 20.00, currency: "EUR", category: "Home", notes: "More Money")
addNewIncomeRecord("2", date: "11-25", description: "Rent", amount: 50.00, currency: "EUR", category: "Home", notes: "Rent Money")
addNewIncomeRecord("3", date: "11-25", description: "Hair", amount: 10.00, currency: "EUR", category: "Medical"  ,notes: "HairCut")

let filteredArray = dataArray.filter { $0["category"] as? String == "Home" }
let amounts = filteredArray.flatMap { $0["amount"] as? Double }
print(amounts)
```

Here's the solution making use of a `struct`.

```
struct Income {
    let id: String
    let date: String
    let description: String
    let amount: Double
    let currency: String
    let category: String
    let notes: String
}

var dataArray = [Income]()
var sum = 0.00

func addNewIncomeRecord(_ id: String, date: String, description: String, amount: Double, currency: String, category: String, notes: String) {
    let income = Income(id: id, date: date, description: description, amount: amount, currency: currency, category: category, notes: notes)

    dataArray.append(income)
}

addNewIncomeRecord("1", date: "11-25", description: "Money", amount: 20.00, currency: "EUR", category: "Home", notes: "More Money")
addNewIncomeRecord("2", date: "11-25", description: "Rent", amount: 50.00, currency: "EUR", category: "Home", notes: "Rent Money")
addNewIncomeRecord("3", date: "11-25", description: "Hair", amount: 10.00, currency: "EUR", category: "Medical"  ,notes: "HairCut")

let filteredArray = dataArray.filter { $0.category == "Home" }
let amounts = filteredArray.map { $0.amount }
print(amounts)
```

Using a `struct` has many advantages. It's type safe for each field. You can make it `Codable` which makes it a lot easier to save and read from a file.